# nrwl/nx monrepo nestjs build error Cannot find module '@nestjs/common'

Tags: angular, nestjs, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I'm using nrwl/nx monorepo in project angular as frontend and nestjs as backend api. when I'm trying to make a build os both apps angular build up and running successfully when I'm starting the nestjs main.js getting below error

```
Error: Cannot find module '@nestjs/common'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.@nestjs/common (/home/ubuntu/****/apps/***-api/main.js:4662:18)
at __webpack_require__ (/home/ubuntu/****/apps/****-api/main.js:20:30)
at Object../apps/*****api/src/main.ts (/home/ubuntu****-lab/apps/*****api/main.js:2997:18)
at __webpack_require__ (/home/ubuntu/*****/apps/**** api/main.js:20:30)
at Object.0 (/home/ubuntu/*****-lab/apps/*****-api/main.js:4650:18)
at __webpack_require__ (/home/ubuntu/****-lab/apps/*****-api/main.js:20:30)
```

Comment: What's your build command? Do you have the `@nestjs/common` module installed via npm/yarn/pnpm? Is the error happening at compile time or run time?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel basically the command was npm run appsName:build —prod. 
The project is running on the dev server all package are installed via npm. And run time there is now error showing only shows that build success and inside folder main.js and main.map.ja and assets are available. I’m deployed it on the server and start it using node / pm2 that the error was showing module not found. Runtime error

Comment: How did you deploy it? Do you have dependencies installed on your server where you deployed it as well? Nx webpacks the server code to a `main.js`, but it doesn't bring in any of the `node_modules` like it does for Angular, so you still need your prod dependencies

Comment: @Jay McDoniel I’m build and deployed it using github action and as you mentioned I’m installed the depen. On the server is it’s running. 

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As it was understood, the building and the deployment of code happened from outside where the server was located. Nx webpacks the server code to a main.js, but it doesn't bring in any of the node_modules like it does for Angular, so you still need your prod dependencies. Installing the prod dependencies on the server will fix this.